# How to lose 40lbs

Tags: weight-loss, diet

I've been obese since 2008. I am a 20-year-old male who weighs 208lbs. I'm 5'10 with no medical conditions. I would like to lose 40lbs within 6 months.
Recently I started to go to the gym. I have time to gym 4 times per week. **I would like to have your suggestion for a diet and workout**.
I am planning to have an oat-based diet as below:

```
7am: 1/2cup oats + steamed milk
9am: apple
1pm: 1/2 cup oats + steamed mik
3pm: banana
5pm: 50g peanuts
7pm: 1/2 cup oats + steamed milk
9pm: black coffee'
```

Thank you!!

[image][image: this is my current body]

Comment: Besides the answers you also don't need to have 7 tiny meals a day, you can probably have larger breakfast / lunch / dinner that will keep you more satiated.

Answer (score 4):

The dietary pattern you give in the question is very ill conceived. I’m neither a doctor, nor a dietician, but the diet you give is woefully incomplete. Will it take the weight off? Most definitely. But it could also lead to anemia, significant loss of muscle tissue, vitamin deficiencies, and a host of other complications associated from a severe calorie and nutrient deficit. *Please* consult with a doctor or dietician for some guidance on establishing a healthy dietary pattern with an appropriate calorie deficit. This will look like a good daily dose of lean protein (100+ g daily), modest fat intake coming from mostly *unsaturated* sources (nuts and legumes are great for this), modest carb intake coming from sources other than simple sugars (think whole grains and again, legumes), and piles and piles and fruits and fibrous vegetables of all different colors for their rich vitamin and mineral content, digestive health benefits, and great satiety management.

Also don’t drink coffee at 9 pm. Caffeine negatively affects sleep, and poor sleep quality is a *strong* correlate with loss of appetite control, impaired weight loss, and weight gain.

Answer (score 3):

One question about your goals that will help refine the program(s) you look at, what do you want? Just to lose weight? Or build towards a specific body or sport? And Tl; DR; - Attention to diet and a good basic strength program such as Stronglifts or Starting Strength. Now see below.

There is only one thing that you absolutely need to lose weight.

Discipline.

The magic formula to lose weight is very simple. Eat less calories than you expend in activity. That's it. But it takes the one thing I noted above.

To start - You will need to be absolutely honest with yourself, get an accurate weighing, and then plug your values into a few different BMR calculators (Find ones that use Harris Benedict, Mifflin St Jeor, etc) and get the average. Be very honest about your daily activity, and add in activity calories. That's your daily limit. Eat less than that, or exercise more, and you will lose weight.

To begin, you will need a food diary. Record everything you eat or drink. Look at *actual* portion sizes and compare that to how much you eat. Do that for three to seven days and see where your calories sinks are. Then start making changes to your diet. Don't do it all at once, or you will backslide. The first week, don't each Chips Ahoy cookies at night (50 calories PER COOKIE. I say that because that is my weakness :D). Then the next week, swap out a sugar snack for carrots and hummus. And so forth. Aim for a couple hundred calories deficit a day. (Oh, and ignore 3500 calories = 1 lb of weight loss. That's a badly equated myth). Ignore the "name" diets, many of them were created for a different medical need (Keto) or to sell books (almost any other diet). Shop the edges of the store, eat mostly foods you actually have to prepare, and aim for 50% carbs, 30-35% protein and 15-20% healthy fats.

Next pick a strength program to start. You will need to build basic muscle mass, and muscle burns more calories than fat, so as you build muscle you are creating more calorie deficits. Also be honest here, work a full body, not just the trophy muscles.

In the beginning, you may lose a lot of weight quickly. Some of that will be water weight, but you will inevitably slow down. Don't get discouraged, you didn't gain your fat mass in three months, you probably won't lose it in three months. Ignore the scale for the most part, as muscle also weighs more than the equivalent amount of fat mass. If you changed all your fat for muscle, you would actually gain weight.

You will have ups and downs, weeks where you do everything right and still gain weight, and so forth. Don't be discouraged, it's a long journey. I don't like the term diet, because that (a lot of the time) indicates a closed end process, rather look at it as a body shaping plan.

You've taken the first step, wanting to change. Now take the next steps, and keep us updated on your progress.